# Как занять всё свободное место картинкой? (Bootstrap/HTML)

Tags: bootstrap

В общем, делаю страницу на Bootstrap, сделал Navbar, сделал Footer.
Присвоил тегу `body` классы `d-flex flex-column` и стиль `"min-height: 100vh"`
Структурно код выглядит так:

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body class="d-flex flex-column" style="min-height: 100vh">
    <nav>...</nav>

    <img src="{{ url_for("static", filename="images/authorization-bg.jpg") }}" alt="" class="img-fluid">

    <footer>...</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Код `footer`'а: https://pastebin.com/stakqrrb
Код `navbar`'a: https://pastebin.com/Kj0WeuiV

Без кода `<img>` между этими тегами, всё работает как надо - footer прижимается к низу, а навбар так и стоит сверху
Я использую bootstrap **5.0.2**, и [тут](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/images/) сказано про `img fluid`, я его попробовал, он действительно растягивает картинку на всю ширину, но вот высота у него уходит за рамки, и я не знаю как её ограничить. Соотношение сторон мне не сильно важно, поэтому можете предлагать решения связанные с этим. [Тут видео-демонстрация](https://youtu.be/jCnwLaGL5jg) того, что есть сейчас

Comment: Вообще, я собираюсь этот img использовать как задний фон. Если на нём лучше установить абсолютное позиционирование, то скажите мне об этом. И дайте хотя-бы наводку на то, как это можно сделать. Я впервые делаю нормальный и функциональный сайт, поэтому любые советы мне в помощь.

Comment: Это из-за того, что img растянута я так понял на 100vh, а <nav> занимает тоже определённую высоту, вот и получается 100vh + nav. Такие background-ы лучше в стилях прописывать, а не в hmtl.

Answer (score 0):

может быть попробовать рисовать фон не картинкой, а градиентом, добавив в css стиль background: linear-gradient(to top right, #00bfff, #000080);

что касается использования абсолютов - их лучше избегать, потому что блоки с абсолютным позиционированием могут двигать остальные блоки вокруг себя, не пуская их на нужное место.